# How to stop hover effect? (no JavaScript)

Tags: html, css

I have a horizontal menu with hover effect that shows a drop down menu. When I resize the window, I want this menu to become vertical but stop the hover effect. is there a way to do this?

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@300;400;700&display=swap');

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

header{
    box-shadow: 5px 0px 5px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
}

.headerWrapper{
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}


/* Horizontal Menu Styles */


.mainMenuUl{
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 5px;
    position: relative;
}

.mainMenuUl li a{
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 60px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    color: #5a5a5a;
}

.mainMenuUl li a[active]{
    background-color: #383838;
    color: #fff;
}

.mainMenuUl li a:hover{
    background-color: #383838;
    color: #fff;
}

.mainMenu li:hover > .subMenuUl{
    /* visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1; */
    display: block
}

.subMenuUl{
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgb(0 0 0 / 18%);
    /* visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0; 
    თუ ამ ოფშენს ვრთავ მაშინ ჰამბურგერ მენიუს ჰოვერზე მიყვება და ვერ ვაჩერებ რომ +_ზე იმუშავოს*/
    display: none;
}

.mainMenu .subMenuUl li{
    position: relative;
}

.mainMenu .subMenuUl li a{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
    padding: 0 0 0 7px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 230px;
    transition: all .3s ease 0s;
}

.subMenuUl li i{
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}


.subMenuUl li:last-child{
    border: none;
}

.subMenuUl.sub{
    right: -230px;
    top: 20px;
    position: absolute;
}

.subMenuUl li:hover .subMenuUl.sub{
    right: -230px;
    top: 0;
    transition: all .3s;
}

/* Hamburger Menu Button Style */

.hamburger{
    display: none;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
}

.hamburger a{
    color: black
}

.hamburger i{
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.hamburger input {
    display: none;
}

.fa-solid.fa-xmark{
    display: none;
    margin-left: 3px;
}

/* Hide Hamburger Icon */

.hamburger input:checked + label .fa-solid.fa-bars{
    display: none;
}

/* Show Close Icon */

.hamburger input:checked + label .fa-solid.fa-xmark{
    display: block;
}

/* Show Main Menu on Hamburger Click */

.hamburger:has(input:checked) + .mainMenu{
    display: block;
}

/* Main Menu Styles on Hamburger Click */



.hamburger:has(input:checked) + .mainMenu .mainMenuUl{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 80px;
    width: 70%;
    right: 2.5%;
}

.hamburger:has(input:checked) + .mainMenu .mainMenuUl li{
    background-color: black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    display: block;
}



.hamburger:has(input:checked) + .mainMenu .mainMenuUl li a{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
    color: #fff5f5;
}


.hamburger:has(input:checked) + .mainMenu .mainMenuUl li a .fa-solid.fa-angle-down{
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.hamburger:has(input:checked) + .mainMenu .mainMenuUl li a[active]{
    background-color: black;
}

.hamburger:has(input:checked) + .mainMenu .mainMenuUl li a:hover{
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}

.fa-solid.fa-plus{
    color: white;
}

.plusBtnBorder{
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    padding: 0 20px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    display: none;
}

.plusBtnBorder input{
    display: none;
}

.hamburger:has(input:checked) + .mainMenu .mainMenuUl li a .plusBtnBorder{
    display: block;
}

.plusBtnBorder:hover{
    background-color: black;
}


/* Hamburger SubMenu */

.hamburger:has(input:checked) + .mainMenu li:has(:hover) > .subMenuUl{
    position: relative;
}

.hamburger:has(input:checked) + .mainMenu li:has(:hover) > .subMenuUl li a{
    padding: 0 0 0 40px;
}















@media screen and (min-width: 1440px) {
    .headerWrapper{
        width: 75%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .headerWrapper{
        width: 80%;
    }

    .mainMenuUl li a{
        padding: 0 7px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .headerWrapper{
        width: 90%;
        padding: 20px 0;
    }

    .hamburger{
        display: block;
    }

    .mainMenu{
        display: none;
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="headerWrapper">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="img/logo.webp" alt="logo">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="menu">
                <div class="hamburger">
                    <a href="#">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="check">
                        <label for="check">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i>
                        </label>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <nav class="mainMenu">
                    <ul class="mainMenuUl">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" active>
                                <span>Home
                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span class="plusBtnBorder">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="vMenu">
                                    <label for="vMenu">
                                        <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
                                    </label>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="subMenuUl">
                                <li><a href="#">Home Version 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Home Version 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Home Version 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Home Version 4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">
                                <span>
                                    Portfolio
                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span class="plusBtnBorder">
                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="subMenuUl">
                                <li><a href="#">Boxed Style <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                                    <ul class="subMenuUl sub">
                                        <li><a href="#">Gutter 4 Column</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Gutter 3 Column</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Gutter 2 Column</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">No Gutter 4 Column</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">No Gutter 3 Column</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">No Gutter 4 Column</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Wide Style <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                                    <ul class="subMenuUl sub">
                                        <li><a href="#">Gutter 6 Column</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Gutter 4 Column</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Gutter 3 Column</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Gutter 2 Column</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">No Gutter 6 Column</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">No Gutter 4 Column</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">No Gutter 3 Column</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">No Gutter 2 Column</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Card Style <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                                    <ul class="subMenuUl sub">
                                        <li><a href="#">Card Box 4 Column</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Card Box 3 Column</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Card Box 2 Column</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Card Full Width 6 Column</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Card Full Width 4 Column</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Card Full Width 3 Column</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Card Full Width 2 Column</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Masonry Box <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                                    <ul class="subMenuUl sub">
                                        <li><a href="#">Masonry Standard</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Masonry Standard 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Box 4 Column</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Box 3 Column</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Box 2 Column</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Gutter Less 4 Column</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Gutter Less 3 Column</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Gutter Less 2 Column</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Masonry Wide <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                                    <ul class="subMenuUl sub">
                                        <li><a href="#">Masonry Standard</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Masonry Standard 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Full Width 4 Column</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Full Width 3 Column</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Full Width 2 Column</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Portfolio Details <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                                    <ul class="subMenuUl sub">
                                        <li><a href="#">Portfolio Details 1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Portfolio Details 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Portfolio Details 3</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">
                                <span>
                                    Blog <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span class="plusBtnBorder">
                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="subMenuUl">
                                <li><a href="#">Blog Left Sidebar</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Blog Right Sidebar</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Full Width 3 Column</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Full Width 4 Column</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Blog Post Details</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: did you try adding the hover-styles into the media-queries?

Comment: tried like this:

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .mainMenu li:hover > .subMenuUl{
        pointer-events: none;
    }

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a media query around the hover effect like shown on the following example:

```
@media (min-width: 767px){
  .mainMenu li:hover > .subMenuUl{
      /* visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1; */
      display: block
  }
}
```

The hover effect will only be shown when the screen-width is bigger than 767px.

For some more research about media query read the following article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Please refrain from using or sharing w3schools where possible - they are known for outdated, unhelpful and in some cases dangerous information that can lead to security issues in your projects. Please refer to either official or more reputable sources, in this case, the reputable source would be the MDN [media queries guides](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: thanks it helped , I used: 

@media screen and (min-width: 993px) {
    .mainMenu li:hover > .subMenuUl{
        display: block
    }
}

Comment: @CanO'Spam Really? Never heard that before. We even learned 50% of coding in school from w3schools.

Comment: [This should help explain](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com#:~:text=But%20look%20at%20what%20some,for%20good%20reasons%20not%20to.&text=W3Schools%20is%20not%20regarded%20as,JavaScript%20is%20MDC%27s%20JavaScript%20Guide.). W3schools has it's uses, but not to be taken as the law or a very good place to learn from. If nothing else- who can maintain documentation for all the languages they do and keep it properly up to date

Comment: @CanO'Spam alright thanks for the information. I'm going to keep that in mind and I changed the link of my answer to.